# JavaScript: How to move a DIV with a HREF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to create a simple HTML game of Point-and-click and I'd like to move my character on the screen. Now, I can do it with buttons, but I'd like to put images with hrefs that my character moves without the button. For example, when I click on the men, I'd like that Mario Moves to the men. My code is this:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>  
<center>
<button id="go2"><-</button> 
<button id="go">-></button> 
</center>  
<script> 
$( "#go" ).click(function() { 
  $('#Walk').attr('src','https://orig02.deviantart.net/8996/f/2014/244/d/e/mario_by_nintentofu-d7xicg0.gif') 
  $( "#Prota" ).animate({ 
    left: "550", 
  }, 4500 ); 
}); 
$( "#go2" ).click(function() { 
  $('#Walk').attr('src','https://orig02.deviantart.net/8996/f/2014/244/d/e/mario_by_nintentofu-d7xicg0.gif') 
  $( "#Prota" ).animate({ 
    left: "0", 
  }, 4500 ); 
}); 
</script>  

</div>
<div id='Fondo' style="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999999;margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; background-color:#000000; height:600; width:800">
<img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/6ddc/f/2018/003/4/b/principepio_by_darklordwriter-dbyrqix.png" alt="" />
</div>
<div id='Objetivo' style="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999999;margin-left: 225px; margin-top: 400px; height:100; width:100">
<img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/finalfantasy/images/d/d0/FFRK_Thief_FFI.png" alt="">
</div>
<div id='Prota' style="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999999;margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 400px; height:100; width:100">
<img src="https://orig02.deviantart.net/8996/f/2014/244/d/e/mario_by_nintentofu-d7xicg0.gif" alt="" id='Walk'>
</div>
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please revise your basic English... *«tha ade that»* is unclear.

Comment: Thanks @Johannes ;) So now... How do you want the animation to trigger if there is no button?

Comment: I think he is trying to trigger the animation by clicking images instead of the buttons

Comment: That could be on mouse move too.... Or on a interval. So Isaac, please edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: Well, with this small edit, I can say: `$("#Objectivo").on("click", function(){...})` would be a handler for the clicks on "the man"... Is that all your question?

Comment: Yes, but It doesn't work and I cannot see the error :'(

Comment: Why not just use `<img>` inside `<button>` elements?  They are semantic elements.  Don't use an element just for the way it renders, use it's semantic meaning and then style accordingly with CSS.

Comment: Because I don't want to lose the transaparence of the PNG image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example, you add an event listener to the object you want Mario to walk to, and then use the offsetLeft property to find where (relatively speaking) to move him.  Here I've subtracted the offsetWidth value so Mario doesn't stand right on top of him.  If Mario approaches from the right, you would want to check for that and instead add the offsetWidth value.

```js
$("#Objetivo").click(function () {
  
  $( "#Prota" ).animate({ 
    left: this.offsetLeft - this.offsetWidth
  }, 1000 );     

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>  

<div id='Fondo' style="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999999;margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; background-color:#000000; height:600; width:800">
<img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/6ddc/f/2018/003/4/b/principepio_by_darklordwriter-dbyrqix.png" alt="" />
</div>
<div id='Objetivo' style="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999999;margin-left: 225px; margin-top: 400px; height:100; width:100">
<img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/finalfantasy/images/d/d0/FFRK_Thief_FFI.png" alt="">
</div>
<div id='Prota' style="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999999;margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 400px; height:100; width:100">
<img src="https://orig02.deviantart.net/8996/f/2014/244/d/e/mario_by_nintentofu-d7xicg0.gif" alt="" id='Walk'>
</div>
```